# issue in getting data with getGEO in R

Tags: r

I want to download the soft file of the GPL6480 platform in R.

I've used this command :

> gset<-getGEO("GPL6480")

but I faced with this problem:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov
File stored at: 
/tmp/RtmpbHgZqQ/GPL6480.soft
Error in file(fname, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(myurl, destfile, mode = mode, quiet = TRUE, method = getOption("download.file.method.GEOquery")) :
  download had nonzero exit status
2: In file(fname, "r") :
  cannot open file '/tmp/RtmpbHgZqQ/GPL6480.soft': No such file or directory
```

I googled for this problem but I can't find the answer. acctauly i don't know that what is the problem exactly.you should know that my connection to net is ok.

I'm using R version 3.2.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 trusty
tnx mansoor

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the internet? The message "Could not resolve host: www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov" would imply that there was no DNS server available to loop up the IP address for what website. Also, you should be clear where the `getGEO` function comes from as it is not present in base R.

Comment: getGEO is come from geoquery package and I'm surfing the web while I working with the R maybe the problem is just connecting to ww.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov